# Backup of system drive backups to a different partition than the original

Tags: partitioning, backup

I want to backup my system drives, but in the past I have had problems with restoring to different partitions (Even same partitions with a different size)

So I am looking for **procedures** (possibly including software) that will let me backup and restore to different partitions, or at least troubleshoot/adjust partition when it cant be used for restore for some reason.

Mostly Windows system partitions

Comment: Your detail is rather vague for what OS, etc. you're backing up and restoring "system drive" wise. Assuming it's WIndows and not disk encrypted with Bitlocker, Truecrypt, etc. I've had success making on the new drive, ONE large NTFS newly formatted partition, and THEN push your NTFS system partition image(s) to it--it should carve those up accordingly for you afterwards as long as you do that first. Hard telling exactly for an accurate answer as you didn't really give much detail to base a "great" answer; thus, my vague and assumptious "suggested" comment.

Comment: Its typically no "newly formatted hard drive".  Typical use can be to restore an old version to a different partition on the same disk and machine.

Comment: Sure just whatever partition on the  HD (entire or not), I'm just saying format it to NTFS of the same size or larger for the partition image you're going to push to it. The boot attribute would need to be set if you wanted it to be the boot partition though without boot time interaction so I assume you mean a data partition restore rather than OS but either would work. If you have SPACE on an HD that you're pushing a backed up partition image, just format it to be the same size or larger (and file system format), then push to it--a partition, the entire HD, etc. many combinations would work.